# Sequence of R.V.s $z_1, z_2, ...$ s.t. $P(z_i=1)=P(z_i=-1)=\frac 1 2$ converge almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3,$ ...be a sequence of independent random variables s.t. $P(z_i=1)=P(z_i=-1)=\frac 1 2$. Does this sequence converge almost surely?

My intuition is telling me that the sequence will approach the random variable Z? i.e. $z_n->Z$ as $n->\infty$ and Z is just another RV s.t. $P(Z=1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac 1 2$.

Here is my confusion, if a sequence converges almost surely, then $z_i$ should be different for each term s.t. it approaches Z in the end; but in this sequence $z-i$ is the same for every term. So I dont udnersntand.

Comment: No, a sequence of $\pm1$ converges if and only if it is ultimately constant, and this happens with the sequence $(z_i)$ with probability $0$. Note furthermore that you never define the "limit" $Z$ that you pretend exists (and which does not).

Comment: You seem to be confusing different notions of convergence for random variables. Converging almost surely means that the sequence $(z_1, z_2, \ldots)$, taken as a single random variable, has probability 1 of taking on a value which is a convergent sequence. However, if you take the proper notion of convergence of a sequence of random variables (rather than their values), like converging in distribution, then yes, you will have convergence.

Comment: i thought converging almost surely means that $P(lim_{n \to \infty} Xi(w)=X(w)=1$? so why does this definition impy that it takes on a single value? i thuoght it would a single value for each event, i apologize but im a bit new to a.s. convergence

Comment: i mean nothing in the definition is saying X(w) has to be a constant value right?

Comment: Hint: Show that the sequence $(z_i)$ does not converge, almost surely.

Comment: im still confused on the  defintion part.... why doesnt zi converge to Z? $zi(\omega)=Z(\omega)$ for $\omega={-1,1}$ since every zi have the same prob space